# Execute formulas ignoring zero elements

Tags: matlab

I want to run fast Matlab algorithms over Matrices by ignoring zero-elements.

In the past I just worked with a very slow double-for-loop e.g.

```
for i = 1 : size(x,1)
   for j = 1 : size(x,2)
        if x(i,j) ~= 0
            ... do something with x(i,j)
        end
     end
end
```

But how can I make the matrix operation on the whole matrix x?
E.g. how can I run

```
x(i,j) = log(x(i,j)) if x>0 else 0    <-- pseudo code
```

in Matlab on the whole matrix without for loops?

Finally I want to rewrite lines like

```
result = sum(sum((V.*log(V./(W*H))) - V + W*H));
```

with ignoring zeros.

I just need to understand the concept.
In case of need I  could also use NaN instead of zero, but I didn't find e.g. the function

```
nanlog()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  Calculating likelihoods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NaN` as a temporary and make use of the fact that `log(NaN) = NaN`, like so:

```
x(x==0) = NaN;
y = log(x);
y(isnan(y)) = 0;
```

alternatively, you can use logical indexing:

```
x(x~=0) = log(x(x~=0));
```

or, if you want to preserve `x`,

```
y = x;
y(y~=0) = log(y(y~=0));
```

For the example you provide, you can just do

```
result = nansum(nansum((V.*log(V./(W*H))) - V + W*H));
```

assuming that `V == 0` is the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`x~=0` returns you the indices of the locations not equal to zero. Then, you can use them to index corresponding locations of `x` such as follows:

```
>> x = [1 0 2 3; 0 4 0 5]
x =
     1     0     2     3
     0     4     0     5

>> mean(x(:)) %#mean of all elements
ans =
    1.8750

>> mean(x(x~=0)) %#mean of nonzero elements
ans =
     3

>> x(x~=0) = x(x~=0) + 1
x =
     2     0     3     4
     0     5     0     6
```

Comment: I can't use the log function using this method

Comment: @user1141785, petrichor's method works,  x(x>0) = log(x(x>0));

Comment: I didn't get the point why this answer got a -1. I would appreciate a comment so that I can improve it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your example until acai made his comment. You'll get a 'neutral' from me. For me personally the explanation from  Rody was better, so I accept this as the answer.